# laravel5 Eloquent and Query builder

Tags: query-builder, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to achieve something like the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM lists WHERE school_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%'"
```

Eloquent and Query builder

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$results = List::where('school_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->get();
```

This assumes that you have a model called 'List' and a database table called 'lists'. If you do not have a model directly coupled, you could use the following query:

```
$results = DB::table('lists')->where('school_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->get();
```

You can also only get the first result by using `first()` instead of `get()`

Here is the documentation describing the query builder: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries